# Cómo puedo solucionar este error en la terminal cuando intento ejecutar un .exe hecho en lenguaje C

Tags: c, terminal

Buen día, estoy estudiando un curso de lenguaje C, estoy intentando ejecutar mi Hola Mundo y el error que me sale es lo que pego a continuación:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: DWARF error: could not find abbrev number 3874
HolaMundo.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x290): multiple definition of `_mingw32_init_mainargs'; c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x290): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HolaMundo.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2d0): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'; c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2d0):
first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HolaMundo.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2f0): multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'; c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2f0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: HolaMundo.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x310): multiple definition of `atexit'; c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x310): first defined here
```

Uso Windows 8.1, configuré mis variables de entorno en el panel de control, la terminal reconoce el comando gcc para compilar, pero no me permite ejecutar. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hola Mundo\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás compilando y ejecutando tu programa?

Comment: Amigo, puedes colocar el comando con el que estas compilando el programa?

Comment: Ya solucioné, me había confundido de comando. Al intentar ejecutar el .exe le volvía a colocar el gcc adelante, cuando tenía que ingresar solo el nombre del archivo junto con la extensión. Agradezco a todos por tomarse su tiempo de ayudarme.